# zsh: event not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, events, zsh

I'm trying to run my code in VSCode terminal and '***zsh: event not found***' pops out every time I do it. I've tried writing some other simple programs in this workspace, unfortunately to no avail. It seems to be a problem connected to this particular folder or workspace as I don't have this issue running programs from other folders (even those that have the same maternal folder). I have different Python interpreters installed but it doesn't seem to be the issue here as, there is no problem running codes from other workspaces with those interpreters.

Furthermore, I kinda fixed it by just copying all the files to new directory (in the same maternal folder). I can run it there with no issue, but it still annoys me that I had to surrender this folder to some unknown forces (unknown at least for me).

Does anyone know how to fix such issues if they would ever occur in the future?